# Upload a file as part of a form in Spring 4 and thymeleaf

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

I have to create companies and one of the required fields is the company logo. I have created the following form:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 256, message = "{validation.length}")
private String name;

@Size(min = 6, max = 32, message = "{validation.length}")
private String companyId;

@NotNull
private String country;

@NotNull
private String city;

@NotNull
private String state;

@NotNull
private String postalCode;

@NotNull
private String address1;

private String address2;

@NotNull
private String phone1;

private String phone2;

private String fax;

@Email(message = "{validation.invalidChars}")
private String email;

private String website;

private MultipartFile companyLogo;

private boolean status;
```

What I am trying to do is to create the company and upload the company logo as part of the form, this is my thymeleaf form

```
<form action="#" th:object="${createCompanyForm}" method="post" id="save">

<input type="text" name="name" th:field="*{name}" th:value="${createCompanyForm.name}" th:class="form-control" data-rule-required="true"/>

<input type="text" name="companyId" th:field="*{companyId}" th:value="${createCompanyForm.companyId}" />

<input type="file" name="companyLogo" id="logo" th:field="*{companyLogo}" th:value="${createCompanyForm.companyLogo}"/>

</form>
```

This form is submitted with a jquery function

```
function save() {
        var formData = $('#save').serializeArray();        
        $.ajax({
            url : "create",
            type: "POST",
            timeout:5000,
            data: formData,
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            cache: false,
            success:function(response){
                alert(response.message);
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert(response.message);
            }
        });
    };
```

This is my ajax controller

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/create",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public JsonFormResponse<String> postCreateCompany(@Valid CreateCompanyForm form, BindingResult result,
            Locale locale, HttpSession session)
    {
        JsonFormResponse<String> response = new JsonFormResponse<>();
        String message;

        if (result.hasErrors())
        {
            message = getLocalizedMessage(FLASH_CREATE_COMPANY_ERROR, null, locale);
            response.setMessage(message);
            response.setErrors(result);
            response.setStatus(JsonResponseStatus.ERROR);
            return response;

        }

        try
        {
            String filename = form.getCompanyLogo().getOriginalFilename();
            Company company = getCompanyService().create(getCurrentUser(session), form);

            if (company == null) { throw new Exception("Error creating the company."); }
            User user = getCurrentUser();
            user.getCompanies().add(company);
            getUserService().update(user);
            message = getLocalizedMessage(FLASH_CREATE_COMPANY_SUCCESS, new String[]
            {
                    form.getName()
            }, locale);
            response.setMessage(message);
            response.setStatus(JsonResponseStatus.OK);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

            message = getLocalizedMessage(FLASH_CREATE_COMPANY_ERROR, null, locale);
            response.setMessage(message);
            response.setErrors(result);
            response.setStatus(JsonResponseStatus.ERROR);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I am using contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', I tried to use multipart/form-data as content type but I getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

I have added the multipart configuration in my servlet-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"
        p:maxUploadSize="5242880" />
```

But I'm still getting that exception.

Does anybody knows what I am missing?, or does anybody knows where can I find an example of uploading a file as part of a form, I have found a lot of examples but with a single field file field. I really appreciate any advice about this.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?